# What is the opposite of string interpolation?

Tags: terminology, string-interpolation

Suppose you have a string:

```
$MY_PATH/test.txt
```

And suppose `MY_PATH` is defined as `/foo/bar`. After interpolation, the string now looks like this:

```
/foo/bar/test.txt
```

What do you call the *opposite* function? That is, what do you call the act of going from `/foo/bar/test.txt` to `$MY_PATH/test.txt`? Extrapolation?

Comment: I always thought "interpolation" to be a horrible term in that context.

Comment: Indeed.... even some hardcore pythonists have expressed dislike about the "interpolation" name on python

Comment: not that "Regular expression based string-token substitution" would be more popular ;-)

Comment: @Chiguiretor - (don't know about the smiley but) well, IMHO, it would. After all you're not interpolating, you're literally substituing a value. But what I do know ...

Comment: Yeah, "interpolation" is a poor name. I does have the _unfortunate_ advantage that many programmers know what you mean when you say it. That's why I was hoping there was an opposite (good, bad or ugly) term that many programmers would recognize.